# меню категорий, ошибка

Tags: php

В коде ошибка, почему то не понимается функция. Может я использую устаревший PHP или наоборот слишком новую версию.

```php
defined('INFOIN') or die('Access denied');

echo '';

/*====Каталог - получение массива====*/
function get_cat() {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `brands`';
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    return null;
  }

  $cat = array();
  if (mysql_num_rows($res) != 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($res); $i++) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);
      if (empty($cat[$row['parent_id']])) {
        $cat[$row['parent_id']] = array();
        //$cat[] = $row;
      }
      $cat[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
    }
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    //$cat[$row['brand_id']] = $row;      
    return $cat;
  }


  function view_cat($arr, $parent_id = 0) {
    if (empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
      return;
    }
    echo "<ul>";
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]); $i++) {
      echo "<li><a href='?$brand_id=".$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id'].
      "$parent_id=".$parent_id.
      "'>".$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title'].
      "</a>";

      view_cat($arr, $arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
      echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
  }
}
```

Ошибка где-то в функции view_cat, может я не ту переменную записал, но мне кажется, что функция чего-то не делает, так как выводит undefined view_cat

Comment: $arr = get_cat();

echo "<div style='width:450px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #74776'>";

view_cat($arr);
echo "</div>"; (в index.php)

Comment: к html частям в главном индексном файле?

Comment: тут должно срабаватывать так как есть div, вроде бы

Comment: ладно разберёмся, спасибо вам, видимо где-то неправильно прикрутил

Answer (score 0):

Из-за вашего кривого форматирования, вы определили функцию `view_cat()` вложенной в функцию `get_cat()`. Понятно, что она у вас не видна снаружи. Вынесите ее в глобальную область видимости

```
defined('INFOIN') or die('Access denied');

echo '';

/*====Каталог - получение массива====*/
function get_cat() {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM `brands`';
  $res = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$res) {
    return null;
  }

  $cat = array();
  if (mysql_num_rows($res) != 0) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_rows($res); $i++) {
      $row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC);
      if (empty($cat[$row['parent_id']])) {
        $cat[$row['parent_id']] = array();
        //$cat[] = $row;
      }
      $cat[$row['parent_id']][] = $row;
    }
    //while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
    //$cat[$row['brand_id']] = $row;      
    return $cat;
  }
}

function view_cat($arr, $parent_id = 0) {
  if (empty($arr[$parent_id])) {
    return;
  }
  echo "<ul>";
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr[$parent_id]); $i++) {
    echo "<li><a href='?$brand_id=".$arr[$parent_id][$i]['id'].
    "$parent_id=".$parent_id.
    "'>".$arr[$parent_id][$i]['title'].
    "</a>";

    view_cat($arr, $arr[$parent_id][$i]['id']);
    echo "</li>";
  }
  echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: мне нужно переместить саму функцию или место где я её вызваю в другом файле

Comment: Вам нужно **внимательно** пересчитать все `{` и `}` и вставить функцию только после того, как для предыдущей функции закрылась последняя `}`. Форматируйте правильно код и будет вам счастье

Comment: Значит в самом коде нет ошибок, я проверил вроде нет, пока что не могу понять может в контроллере проблема, там вроде все нормально, он получает функцию.

Comment: пробовал заново писать